# CodeIgniter: How to synchronize local and remote databases

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Hotel monitoring web application developed in **CodeIgniter**. 
It monitors each room of a hotel for activities and Sends live data about rooms occupancy, status of electrical switches etc. 
It hosted in **cpanel** web server. I have the same copy of it in my local computer. 
I want to synchronize the 2 databases (ie. in **localhost** and in **remote server**).
Every change in any database should be automaticaly updated to other database.

First I tried to access my remote database from localhost by putting host name as my cpanel Shared IP Address as follos

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
```

where xx.xx.xx.xx is the shared IP of cpanel. but no use.

how should I proceed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you want to synchronize? This seems to be dangerous as if anytime your system got crashed then it'll be also removed from your server too..

Comment: Want to reflect only updates of one database to other

Comment: There are some ways you can do this .. 1. Adding in CI 2 DB connections and modify your update code so update both DB. 2. Use a 3party program that will sink bout DB..

Comment: Would you mind explaning the 1st method clearly?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: The Codeigniter Way**

You can set up a remote access MySQL server:

Tutorial for cpanel here:  https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-
connections-in-cpanel/

Then just set up a new connection in your `database.php` changing the to `$db['remote']['hostname'] = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';`

*Do note that you'll have to make a method to pull in this new data and replace it in your local database, so a script that can be run via cronjob.*

**Option 2: The Master/Slave Way**

You can set up a **Master** database, being the hotel, and a **slave** being your local database. I don't know of a method to do this straight cpanel, but you can do it in phpmyadmin, there's a video on how to do it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfsmnx24gxU

This method would be the most comprehensive/automatic way to do it. It will overwrite any changes in your database though.

**Note that any outside access to a database is potentially insecure. Be aware of this when choosing.**